# How to Convert Currency using google currency API in Php?

Tags: php, api, currency

I am using google currency conversion API in php by using file_get_content but unable to get output because of getting error ,so how to convert any currency by using following  API in Php.

```
<?php  
 function convertCurrency($amount, $from, $to)  
 {  
      $url = "http://www.google.com/finance/converter?a=$amount&from=$from&to=$to";  
      $data = file_get_contents($url);  
      preg_match("/<span class=bld>(.*)<\/span>/",$data, $converted);  
      return $converted[1];  
 }  
 echo convertCurrency(1500, 'USD', 'INR');  
 ?>
```

Getting error like this

```
Message: file_get_contents(http://www.google.com/finance/converter?a=1500&from=USD&to=INR): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden
```

[image]

Comment: it already says `403 Forbidden` , so no, you can't scrape it this way

Comment: @Ghost so how to do this can you please give me suggestion how to solve this currency conversion in php

Comment: you can check out these answers here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3139879/how-do-i-get-currency-exchange-rates-via-an-api-such-as-google-finance

Comment: try to check which of them fits your requirements

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
function thmx_currency_convert($amount){
    $url = 'https://api.exchangerate-api.com/v4/latest/USD';
    $json = file_get_contents($url);
    $exp = json_decode($json);

    $convert = $exp->rates->USD;

    return $convert * $amount;
}
echo thmx_currency_convert(9);
```

Answer (score 1):

A Bit Late, but it might help Some One, 
As [Benjamin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/759866/benjamin) said

> You're not calling an actual API, you're scraping a web page, which means that:
>
> - you're most likely violating Google's TOS
> - you're more likely to get rate-limited (or be detected as abuse and be blacklisted) at some point if you're fetching this page too often

**The Code Snippet**

```
$url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=INR+to+USD";//Change Accordingly
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
$data = explode("1 Indian Rupee = ",$result);//Change Accordingly
$one_inr_rate_to_usd = (float) substr($data[1],0,7);
```

Answer (score 0):

I already answered a [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50691463/759866) just a few days ago (the code was pretty much the same as yours).

I encourage you to read my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50698038/759866):

> You're not calling an actual API, you're scraping a web page, which means that:
>
> - you're most likely violating Google's TOS
> - you're more likely to get rate-limited (or be detected as abuse and be blacklisted) at some point if you're fetching this page too often

This is probably what you encountered here. You've most likely been blacklisted.

Solution: use a proper API such as [OpenExchangeRates](https://openexchangerates.org/).